# Target first element on either side of .slick-current slide with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm trying to target the two slides on either side of `.slick-current` when using Slick Slider. Either via CSS or JavaScript/jQuery. Is there a way to add a class to these two slides?

On [this code example](https://codepen.io/ConduciveMammal/pen/MXjxqp), when slide 2 is activated, I'd like to select slides 1 & 3.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your current initialization, you could hook to the `afterChange` event to get the previous and next slides, using the slide index passed as an argument for the event callback:

```
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    var next = $('.slider').find('[data-slick-index="'+(currentSlide+1)+'"]');
    var prev = $('.slider').find('[data-slick-index="'+(currentSlide-1)+'"]');
    console.log(next, prev);
});
```

Or you could just get the current slide index, and then get the previous and next slide using the same technique:

```
var currentSlide = $('.slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
var next = $('.slider').find('[data-slick-index="'+(currentSlide+1)+'"]');
var prev = $('.slider').find('[data-slick-index="'+(currentSlide-1)+'"]');
console.log(next, prev);
```

Comment: Oh that looks perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: @ConduciveMammal Great! Tick it if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Hmmm so I've updated my CodePen, it works, but it's not removing the class again afterChange. I added a .each() on `.slide` to remove the class but seems that doesn't work.

Also, is it possible to add the class during change like `.slick-current` does so that it occurs whilst the slider is transforming?

Comment: @ConduciveMammal can you post a link to the updated codepen, or it's the same?

Comment: I think it's the same but if not, it's: https://codepen.io/ConduciveMammal/pen/MXjxqp

Comment: Ahh yeah, the link stays the same

Comment: @ConduciveMammal well you could do it, but you will face an issue at the "borders" of the slid (when reaching the beginning and the end. https://codepen.io/muecas/pen/yEamjj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172705/discussion-between-conducivemammal-and-muecas).